# cxfreeze error: script or a list of modules must be specified

Tags: python

I am a python noob, so this may be a stupid question, but when I tried to use cxfreeze to export a python script to exe (using python 3.3) I get this:

`cxfreeze.py: error: script or a list of modules must be specified`

This is the command I was using:

`cxfreeze.py script.py --target-dir dist`

The script had been copied into the `C:\Python33\Scripts` directory. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try adding the setup script you are using.

Comment: Have you made a setup.py script that is defining how cx_freeze will handle to freezing?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar command working... then it stopped.  Turns out that adding `C:\Cygwin64\bin` to my path causes that message to come up and without cx_Freeze works fine.  Note that I do have both Windows and Cygwin Python installs so I assume that my issue is related to conflicting libraries being found.

Note that I am actually calling MinGW Make from a cmd.exe prompt in Windows 7 against a makefile which calls cx_Freeze using Python 3.4.